# Urgent Help: Company asked me for my research proposal

Tags: research-process

One of the companies I requested permission to recruit participants for my study is asking me to provide my research proposal. My question is, should I send the actual proposal (about 100 pages) or a summary? Is it ethical? Am I allowed to do that? 
I cannot contact anyone from my school to ask these questions but until Monday. I really would like to reply to the company right away because I need the participants.
If I have to send a summary only, do you know if there is a format for that?

Your prompt assistance is appreciated!

CS

Comment: Explain why it may be a problem to reveal your proposal? Is the company a potential competitor? Is it so original that you fear a leak (if so, request a non-disclosure agreement)? Did your advisor ban you from forwarding the proposal (in which case you should ask them)? Normally, it is unlikely that revealing your proposal is a problem, but if you foresee danger,  answer above questions to yourself before proceeding. I do not see how it would be unethical (as long as the secrecy of distractions crucial for the experiment's success are not leaked by the company).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Captain Emacs. This is the first time I will be conducting a study and I was wondering if being asked to provide one's proposal was common.

Comment: I do not know whether it is common wherever you are - they may have real interest or they may want to protect themselves. But, really, the best way forward is to ask your advisor who will know the context.

Comment: If you are in a country where the university doesn't operate on weekends then I would guess businesses don't either (therefore it is expected to not reply until Monday).

Comment: I'm in the USA, but the company that answered me is from abroad and I've received their message this morning that's why I wanted to answer them today.

Answer (score 4):

This is a sufficiently common request that I'm actually surprised that you didn't get it ahead of time. Breaking down your question:

> My question is, should I send the actual proposal (about 100 pages) or a summary?

The actual proposal, with a summary in the front for the TL;DR crowd.

> Is it ethical?

Unless there is identifiable information about your subjects, proprietary information about the other company, etc. in there, is there any reason why it *would* be unethical to send a research proposal? Just asking "Is this ethical" isn't terribly useful - you should have a specific concern. In that case, you could leave out that information with a note as to why it has been omitted. But a research proposal usually doesn't contain information like that.

> Am I allowed to do that?

No one can answer that but your advisor, but I'd be surprised if the answer was "No".

> I cannot contact anyone from my school to ask these questions but until Monday. I really would like to reply to the company right away because I need the participants.

If it would make you more comfortable, you could prep everything and then check early Monday morning - it's doubtful a delay over the weekend is going to change the company's response in a meaningful way.

Comment: I have my proposal ready; my doubt is if I should send them an entire proposal or just an outline; I was wondering if showing the entire document prior to being approved will have ethical repercussions for me. In my proposal I do mention the other organizations that I am planning to include in my study. These can be easily identified. That's the reason of my question.

Comment: I do not know what the role of the approval would be here, for this we do not have enough context. However, mentioning other organisations may be a problem (for you or them). It sounds like you should tread carefully.

Comment: @user47240 This could range from "Not a thing" to "A huge problem" depending on what you mean by "other organizations", what the study is, etc. Just wait until Monday.